# How do I restore the IUSR account used by IIS 6

Tags: iis, iis-6

We mirrored one of our webservers and thus got an IUSR account that was named after the wrong server  `IUSR-SERVER1` when this server's name is SERVER2.

So I went and renamed the user to `IUSR_SERVER2`, but after resetting IIS it kept creating the old IUSR-SERVER1 account. Turns out this is a feature, so I went through the websites in IIS and changed the IUSR that they use to IUSR-SERVER2 then deleted `IUSR-SERVER1`, and this time it stayed deleted.

Then I accidentally deleted `IUSR-SERVER2` so I tried to reset IIS hoping it would be automatically created. Unfortunately this did not occur. Thus I was forced to create a new user and give it a password.

This made the website work but now there is a password associated with the IUSR, is there any other way to create an IUSR so everything is the same as before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the IUSR Password using the following command:

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/anonymoususerpass “P@ssword”
```

You then need to sync it with this command:

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript.exe synciwam.vbs -v
```

Comment: I tried this using the empty string for the password. Then I updated the website in IIS to use the empty string but that didn't work. So instead I was forced to delete the user and recreate it from scratch with a password to get the site up and running again.